# Session Destroyed after user login in oscommerce

Tags: php, session, oscommerce

I have been integrating my website with oscommerce..am facing the problem with session..if I add the products into the cart it works well as usual..but after I logged into the site then I got my previous sessions destroyed..So any one can give any suggestions to get it resolved.Thanks in advance..

Comment: When you login to the cart does it switch to https?

Comment: No..it does not switch to https..

Comment: Also it happens when I switch over to another page after I added the products to cart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `/includes/configure.php` make sure the following entries are set:

```
define('HTTP_COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME.com');
define('HTTPS_COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME.com');
define('HTTP_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('HTTPS_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
```

Replace `YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME` with your site's domain.

Comment: Change `define('STORE_SESSIONS', 'mysql');` to `define('STORE_SESSIONS', '');`